# How to use lasso/ridge regression model in statsmodels?

Tags: python, regression, data-science, data-analysis, statsmodels

I would like to use lasso or ridge regression in my model to handle multicolinearity, but when I try to do so and to watch the summary, i get an error:

```
print(lasso_r.summary())
  File "C:\Users\aleks\PycharmProjects\statistics\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 1177, in summary
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

My code looks the next way:

```
lr = sm.OLS.from_formula("Ozone~Q('Solar.R')+Wind+Temp",data=air)
lasso_r = lr.fit_regularized(method='sqrt_lasso')
print(lasso_r.summary())
```

Could you tell me, please, what could cause this problem and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The method `summary` simply isn't implemented yet for lasso and ridge regression and in general any model from `lr.fit_regularized`, hence the error `NotImplementedError`

`summary` is only available for a normal OLS i.e.
`normal_ols = lr.fit()`